# How to send context from DrizzleContext.Provider to a Class Component / Class Container

Tags: react, drizzle

I'm using the new Context API supported 'drizzle-react' library in my dapp. Can anyone please clarify how to receive the context sent from DrizzleContext.Provider into a "class" component? Check out the example index.js file below. Imagine the < App /> component is a "class" component and not a "function component". For a "function" component, i guess it is pretty straightforward - use < DrizzleContext.Consumer >. But how to get the context (drizzle = {drizzle}) inside the class component ? I tried giving a constructor with context prop like this:

```
constructor(props,context) {...}
```

but this doesnt work. Any ideas ?

my index.js looks like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-jsx -->
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Drizzle, generateStore } from "drizzle";
    import { DrizzleContext } from "drizzle-react";
    import { LoadingContainer } from 'drizzle-react-components'
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    //import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
    import drizzleOptions from './drizzleOptions';

    const drizzleStore = generateStore(drizzleOptions);
    const drizzle = new Drizzle(drizzleOptions, drizzleStore);

        ReactDOM.render(
            (<DrizzleContext.Provider drizzle={drizzle} >
                    <App />
            </DrizzleContext.Provider>),
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that one can use this statement to get the context in class components :

```
MyClassComponent.contextType = DrizzleContext.Consumer;
```

now if we use the following context in constructor :

```
constructor(props,context) {
super(props)
console.log(this.context);
}
```

this will output the context object { drizzle, drizzleState, initialized } to console. Even though I'm not sure if MyClassComponent.contextType is the right way to go by, since I believe it is part of the legacy Context API (correct me if I'm wrong).